# How to match string using regular expression in bats tests?

Tags: bash, bats-core

I know I can check if the result is equal to something, like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bats

@test "Check that total is listed" {
    run ls -l
    [[ ${lines[0]} =~ "total" ]]
}
```

but, what if  I just want to check if the lines[0] is made of several digits and letters? Should I use a regular expression to do that?

Comment: Notice that regex checks match substrings. The test would also be true if you were comparing `XXXtotalXXX`. You need to anchor your regex if you want to match the whole string (as done in the answer).

Answer (score 3):

Use a *regex*, example:

```
$ regex='^[[:alnum:]]+$'
$
$ [[ "1gz0" =~ $regex ]]
$ echo $?
0
$ [[ "1gz_0" =~ $regex ]]
$ echo $?
1
```